# What goes in a Graphic Design portfolio on Slideroom for graduate school?

Tags: portfolio

I'm going to apply to graduate programs this year and Slideroom seems to be the preferred choice for portfolios. I'm wondering about what to put in it and what I'm even able to put in it.

Do I design a nice .pdf in InDesign and then upload it as single pages?

Should those pages be of just the end product or should process by shown?

Do I upload just my finished pieces individually?

Do you just caption the pieces with some sort of built-in system or should captions be designed as parts of the uploaded piece?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ryan,

SlideRoom is a flexible system that can be used by schools in a number of ways. Since there is no single correct way to prepare a portfolio, it is critical that you read the school's instructions. These will often be posted on their main website, or on the Media step within their SlideRoom portal.

As a rule of thumb, you should use individual jpgs when possible, and label them after upload. This gives the school the best preview of your work. Of course, some kinds of content are better as PDF (multi-page catalogs, huge posters with tiny fonts, musical scores, etc). If the school allows/asks for PDF, and it is appropriate for your work, then do that.

Chris Jagers
SlideRoom Director

UPDATE: Ryan, do not add descriptions on the jpgs directly. SlideRoom will provide an interface for labeling all media after it has been uploaded. This will appear much cleaner for reviewers.

Comment: Thanks Chris, is the label you speak of in lieu of putting a description on the actual jpeg?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer as I see you have a role in SlideRoom I especially appreciate the information and hopefully some others will find this too.